# Reports in Crystal Report working on one system but not on other

Tags: crystal-reports

On one PC same formula or report is working properly, but not on the others. So what should i need to check in it to solve this issue. Operating System and version of crystal report are same at both places.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it will be the crystal run times. What are you using to view the report?

Comment: Sorry.. I am using VB Runtime

Comment: Can you elaborate. You can't run crystal reports with just a runtime- you need some form of report viewer? Or are you using the Crystal developer application or Visual Studio?

Comment: I run crystal report through Visual Basic 6.0 application.